# Default LaTeX font for all commands and definitions

Tags: fonts

What is the font that LaTeX uses as default for: the notmal text, the `\bfseries`, the `\itshape` etc and all commands and definitions in the table 43 at page 131 of [this](http://www.lorenzopantieri.net/LaTeX_files/ArteLaTeX.pdf) guide?

I have found some fonts in this directory: `C:\texlive\2011\texmf-dist\fonts\opentype\public\lm`. I suppose that the default font for math is `lmmath-regular.otf`, right?

Comment: Are you looking for `\normalfont`? Or are you looking for `Computer Modern`?

Comment: @Seamus what is the difference between those ? however, i would to know what .otf file latex use for every command/definition

Comment: @FormlessCloud most TeX systems do not use OTF files by default. My answer gives the font names, but they are usually used in `.pk` (bitmap) or `.pfb` (type1) form

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The default font set for TeX is Computer Modern, designed by Knuth specifically for TeX use.

So the 10pt roman font is `cmr10`, the italic `cmti10` bold (extended) `cmbx10` etc.

For mathematics the situation is more complicated as there is not a single font, different characters come from different fonts. The main math italic is `cmmi10`  The main math symbol font is `cmsy10` with big brackets etc coming from `cmex10`.